# I have an error while using my password to login an sudo

Tags: updates, login, pam

Some days ago I received some Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS updates. After these updates I can not login anymore with my password. I am only able to login because I have set up my fingerprints before.
I know the password is the same I'm writing because when I try to change it from settings, if I put the same I have set, ubuntu tells me that this is the same current password.
So, summarizing:
I can login only with the fingerprint even knowing the password is ok  and when I tried to use sudo I get this error

```
[sudo] password for pabloa: 
sudo: PAM authentication error: Module is unknown
sudo: a password is required
```

Please help me. I don't want to format the laptop.

Comment: Did you modify files in the PAM stack (such as /etc/pam.d/common-auth) in order to add fingerprint based authentication?

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, thanks for your answer. I didn't modify anything, and it has been working for months. After an update (on monday) I started with this issue. Everywhere I write or copy/paste my password throws an error saying it is incorrect. But when I try to change it and I put the same pass I receive a message that is the same current pass.